# How to add m² symbol at the end textField in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

how is it possible to add a m² at the end of the textfield?

For example, to add a € character at the end of a textfield, I was able to solve it with the numberFormatter.
[textfield with euro sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au6aT.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have several options. The simplest solution is to use Unicode characters. Just use the superscripted version of the number 2 (U+00B2):

```swift
self.textField.text = "112 m\u{00B2}"
```

[image: Unicode example]

Alternatively you can use `NSAttributedString` or `NSMutableAttributedString`:

```swift
let defaultFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
let superscriptedFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)

let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "112 m", attributes: [.font: defaultFont])
text.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "2", attributes: [.font: superscriptedFont, .baselineOffset: 5]))

self.textField.attributedText = text
```

[image: AttributedString example]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I don't quite understand how to embed your code. For example, how can I include your first option in this TextField.

`TextField("", value: $test, formatter: numberFormatter)`